# Problem with pytz package - Python - Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, package, azure-functions, pytz

I had an Azure function that worked completely fine, then I added the pytz package to my script.

In Azure I am getting the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'.

My requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
azure-functions
pyodbc==4.0.32
requests==2.28.0
pytz==2022.1
```

and the top of my actual script looks like this:

```
import datetime
import logging
import requests
import json
import pyodbc
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
```

When I deploy the function from Python, I can see the packages getting installed in the output EXCEPT for pytz. Is it because in my script it is written as 'from pytz'? I am very new to Python and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has given a solution and troubleshooting steps for this kind of error with detailed explanation that:

> The Module Not Found error may not occur when you're using Windows or macOS for local development. However, the package fails to import on Azure Functions, which uses Linux at runtime. This is likely to be caused by using pip freeze to export virtual environment into requirements.txt

To mitigate this error, there are 2 solutions given by Microsoft which are replace the equivalent package or Handcraft requirements.txt file.

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#the-package-only-supports-windows-or-macos-platforms) given by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I have been over the documentation and have not found any issues with the package. Something I have noticed is that my requirement.txt file is not recognizing updates. For instance, if I delete all of my code and run pip install -r requirement.txt, the terminal still shows all the same packages being installed. Could this be an environment issue?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, In my case the problem was with the python environment. Though the python environment is present make sure you activate the environment.

[image]

After activating i.e., `<Your_Environment_Name>\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

[image]